# How to rollback a SQL Server transaction and use output param?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2016, ssdt, error-handling

I am trying to set an output param in a stored procedure, but I think that when I rollback the transaction I think I'm also rolling back the assignment to `@out`. Is that correct?

If so, how can I return a message and rollback a transaction? I am fetching the `@out` param from C#.

```
create PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp]
@out varchar(2000) output
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    BEGIN TRANSACTION
    BEGIN TRY
        SET @OUT = "success";
        COMMIT TRANSACTION
    END TRY

    BEGIN CATCH
        set @out = 'not success';
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
    END CATCH
END
```

I was originally doing a

```
SELECT 
    ERROR_NUMBER() AS ErrorNumber,
    ERROR_SEVERITY() AS ErrorSeverity,
    ERROR_STATE() AS ErrorState,
    ERROR_PROCEDURE() AS ErrorProcedure,
    ERROR_LINE() AS ErrorLine,
    ERROR_MESSAGE() AS ErrorMessage;
```

...but that didn't help, though I would prefer that method.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A more robust way to write this stored procedure would be:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.sp
AS
BEGIN
    SET XACT_ABORT, NOCOUNT ON;

    BEGIN TRY
        BEGIN TRANSACTION;

        SELECT 1/0; -- An error!

        /* Other good code omitted*/

        COMMIT TRANSACTION;
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0 ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;

        DECLARE @Message nvarchar(2048) = ERROR_MESSAGE();
        DECLARE @Severity integer = ERROR_SEVERITY();
        DECLARE @State integer = ERROR_STATE();

        RAISERROR(@Message, @Severity, @State);
        RETURN -1;
    END CATCH;
END;
```

Note the use of `XACT_ABORT` and nothing of consequence before the `BEGIN TRY`. Also `RAISERROR` is often [preferred](http://sommarskog.se/error_handling/Part2.html#THROW) over `THROW` for reasons covered in the reference below, but importantly:

> In difference to RAISERROR, ;THROW always aborts the batch.

Aborting the batch results in any output parameters [not being assigned](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlprogrammability/2006/06/09/tsql-basics-ii-parameter-passing-semantics/).

Error handling in SQL Server is quirky in the extreme, so I would encourage you to review the seminal work on the topic by Erland Sommarskog: [Error and Transaction Handling in SQL Server](http://sommarskog.se/error_handling/Part1.html).

Comment: What's the use of the TRY/CATCH construct AND XACT_ABORT together? Wouldn't the TRY/CATCH nullify any cases where XACT_ABORT would usually abort the transaction?

Answer (score 3):

Since you're using SQL Server 2016, I would recommend using [`THROW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/throw-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

This will take the error that caused the `TRY` construct to divert to the `CATCH` construct, and throw that same error again.

If you want here, you could also log the error to a table, do any cleanup exercises that the `ROLLBACK` won't do, etc.

To be clear, to the calling application, this will be an exception and not a result set.

Note: The statement prior to the `THROW` **must** be terminated with a semicolon, otherwise it may be interpreted as e.g. `ROLLBACK TRANSACTION THROW` with `THROW` as the transaction or savepoint name.

Comment: Question - when I use `throw <err n0.>, "msg", <some other no.>`. It says err no. must be `> 5000 < some very large number`. But the ERROR_NUMBER() function returns a small value. This seems completely useless to me... am i missing something?

Comment: @ZachSmith if you want to re-throw the same error just use `THROW;` in your catch block.  If you supply an error number it must be in the custom error number rage of  >= 50000.